# Когда поздно делать рефакторинг? Численные характеристики

Tags: рефакторинг

В книгах (например Фаулер "Рефакторинг...") можно найти некоторые рекомендации, когда не нужно делать рефакторинг, просто переписать (есть также мнения, что никогда не нужно переписывать). Но как можно это понять, когда ситуация неоднозначная (или нужно доказать или опровергнуть, с минимумом субъективизма)? Можно ли посчитать какие-то характеристики? Предполагаю, что отношение времени добавления одной условной фичи в "плохой код" ко времени добавления такой же фичи в "хороший код" (условно `Kt`) - (хоть какая-то) коррелирующая с реальностью количественная оценка. Какова граница, когда не следует рефакторить, а нужно переписывать? Это `Kt >= 3` или `>=10`, `>=100`?

Comment: А как Вы измерите время добавление функционала в несуществующий хороший код?

Comment: Когда добавление новой фичи будет вызывать дестабилизацию всего остального и никак не будет получаться сбалансировать все это, то мнение "никогда не нужно переписывать" быстро пойдет лесом )

Comment: @edem, ваше замечание уместно, возможна, пожалуй, только умозрительная оценка.